# How to get out of the rails console if I accidentally misplace quotes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sometimes in my rails development, I'll run into a problem where I accidentally mismatch my quotes. Normally when this happens sometimes I'll hit `quit` or `exit` and I can usually get out of the mistake. But once in a while, I'll find myself in a scenario like the one below:

[image]

I've made a mistake in my string interpolation in the query above and now I can't seem to get out of this no matter what. So my question is, what is the proper way to exit out this dilemma? Sometimes I nuke my entire shell and restart, but there has to be an easier more elegant way to do so.

Comment: BTW, closing the parentheses got me out of it. But is there a failsafe command I can use to just abort when it gets this messy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hit ctrl-d, and then type `exit` to close the console.

ctrl-d will let you escape from the mismatched quotes. it sends an [End-of-Transmission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character) sequence, so the current statement ends and it lets you start a new statement.

Just tested in IRB and Rails console:

```
irb(main):001:0> "test
```

hitting ctrl-d:

```
irb(main):002:0"
```

hitting ctrl-d again:

```
irb(main):002:0> 
SyntaxError: (irb):1: unterminated string meets end of file from /usr/local/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

back to normal:

```
irb(main):002:0>
```